# Mac app to show cumulative CPU usage?

Tags: macos, performance, activity-monitor

Activity Monitor will show you how much CPU time the *current instances* of each process have taken. I want an app that will show the total CPU time *all instances* of each process have taken, so I can (for instance) see what's draining my MacBook's battery the most on average.

If this exists, I can't find it. Does it exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want `sa` and `accton` commands to dump accounting information to a file.

[Here's an article that's a bit old](http://encodable.com/tech/blog/2005/10/28/Simple_Linux_Process_Accouting). The perl script at the end works well - look out for * characters in the shell - those might need to get filtered or the input sanitized if the perl script doesn't show you totals.

Comment: Gehhh. I don't mind occasional command-line stuff, and I can script a tiny bit, but generating and parsing log files does not sound like my idea of a good time, particularly for something that matters as relatively little as this. Thanks for your answer, though; if my need should ever grow greater I will certainly return here to start down the rabbit hole.

Comment: Indeed - it's not friendly. Some day, some developer might make a nicer tool that runs in a window. As bad as this is, it's the only tool I'm aware of that attempts to sum the small accounting times to get a bigger view.